# Why is differentiation of $x^2$ equal to $2x$ and not $2x + 1$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Tbh, I know very little about differentiation and so this should most probably be a dumb question, but I was just trying out a few examples and saw that $d/dx$ of $x^2$ actually appears to be $2x + 1$ and that of $x^3$ appears to be $3x^2 + 3x + 3$ (for an increase of $1$).
Then why do we use only $2x$ and $3x^2$ instead?

Is this for simplification?
Thanks.

Examples:

$2^2 \rightarrow  3^2$ is actually an increase of $7 (2 * 2 + 1)$.

$3^3 \rightarrow 4^3$ is actually an increase of $37 (3 * 3^2 + 3 * 3 + 1)$

Comment: I think you computed their *finite differences*: $\Delta[f](x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ or something similar. It is a related but a different concept.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}~$ equals $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 2xh + h^2 - x^2}{h}.$

Comment: Your answers equate to differentiation of a function $f(x) = x^2$ in discrete calculus. Instead of taking the difference between outputs at the limits of the difference between in the inputs, you are taking the difference between outputs with static, incremental differences between the inputs. $(x+1)^2 - x^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 -x^2 = 2x + 1$.

Comment: Please show your work, so that we don't have to guess what happened. Cheers!

Comment: To emphasize, you found the average rate of change of $f(x)$ from $x=2$ to $x=3$ or from a value to another value one larger in general.  The derivative does not talk about average rates of change over large intervals like this, but rather about *instantaneous* rates of change, heavy emphasis on the "*instantaneous*" part of this statement.

Comment: The point of differentiation is to find the rate of change of something. Separate constants (like 1 in this case) dont have any role to play in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x$ goes from $2$ to $3$, $x^2$ increases by $(2 \times 2) + 1.$

This implies that the rate of change is **about** $(2 \times 2) + 1 = 5$, throughout the interval of $2 \leq x \leq 3.$

However, it does not imply that the rate of change, at the specific point $x = 2$ is $5$.  In fact, per the comments, the rate of change at $x = 2$ is $4$, the rate of change at $x = 3$ is $6$, and the effect of $x$ going from $2$ to $3$ is that the rate of change is around $5$, throughout the interval.

Comment: Ok, so I was computing the derivatives for intervals of 1. As the actual interval for d/dx approaches 0, the other terms wouldn't exist.
I didn't even know that discrete calculus was also a thing lol.
Thanks.